# Internet Explorer 10 - jQuery click on select option doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I've tried to map an event jQuery event listener `click(function(){//doStuff})` to an `<option>` element, but on click/focus, IE doesn't execute my function.

In FF and Chrome, it works perfectly.  In IE10, the click option doesn't work; neither the HTML element `onClick="doFunction()"`, nor the `on.('click',...)` event.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvJQQ/)

```
<select id="someId" name="someName" size="10" multiple="yes">
<option value="ALL">--All--</option>
<option value="X1">X1</option>
<option value="X2">X2</option>
<option value="X3">X3</option>
<option value="X4">X4</option>
<option value="X5">X5</option>
<option value="X6">X6</option>
<option value="X7">X7</option>
<option value="X8">X8</option>
<option value="X9">X9</option>
</select>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someId option[value="ALL"]').click(function () {
        $('select option').attr('selected', true);
        $('select option[value="ALL"]').eq(0).attr('selected', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't attach a click event to an `<option>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viliam, I'm afraid I have bad news. IE10 will not really fire "click" event for option, instead it will fire it for "select" only. So what you can do is to put "click" event handler on select, track the selected value and act upon that.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JvJQQ/2/)

```
$('#someId').click(function () {
    if ($("#someId option:selected").eq(0).val() === 'ALL') {
        $('select option').prop('selected', true);
        $('select option[value="ALL"]').eq(0).prop('selected', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: works perfectly, i should have tried to map the event on the parent, but i was playing around on the wrong spot.

Comment: This can cause an unexpected behaviour when clicking on a whitespaced-place on the select element, because the click is recognized but the value remains unchanged. Could be combined with a `change` event.